# The relation between $Gal(Z_2(M)/Z_1(M))$ and $Gal(Z_2/Z_1)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Let $L/K$ be a field extension with $K \subset Z_1,Z_2 \subset L$. And furthermore let $M$ be a set completely disjoint with $K,Z_1,Z_2, L$.

If we have $\phi \in Gal(Z_2(M)/Z_1(M))$, then $\phi|_{Z_2} \in Gal(Z_2/Z_1)$.
Now if we have $\psi \in Gal(Z_2/Z_1)$, can we extend $\psi$ in such a way that its now in $Gal(Z_2(M)/Z_1(M))$? (by mapping all of $M$ to itself)

And in this way we have a bijective mapping between $Gal(Z_2/Z_1)$ and $Gal(Z_2(M)/Z_1(M))$?

I know the question might be very trivial, but I still can't shake off the feeling that I've made some mistake, thank you.

And to add, is it true that $Gal(Z_2(M)/Z_1(M))$ is Galois if and only if $Gal(Z_2/Z_1)$ is Galois?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what $M$ is, but I think I do not agree with the first sentence of the second paragraph. There is no reason $\phi$ has to map $Z_2$ to itself, it just has to send it into some subfield of $Z_2(M)$ isomorphic to $Z_2$.

Comment: @hunter You're right, thank you

Comment: Can you explain clearly what you mean with a set completely disjoint?

Comment: @reuns $M$ doesn't share any elements with $L, K, Z_1,Z_2$

Comment: What do you get with $Z_1=\Bbb{Q},Z_2=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3}), M=e^{2i\pi /3}2^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: @reuns Ah you are right, that's a good example, thanks